# how to customize swaggerintegration in hybris

Tags: swagger, openapi, sap-commerce-cloud

I am new in hybris. I need to add my own implementation on **OpenApiCustomiser**. So I want to customize existing **swaggerintegration** . How can I customize it or is there any other way to use my own **OpenApiCustomiser** ?

I tried to use `ant extgen` command but in existing extension template list **swaggerintegration** is not available.